# How to find inverse function of `i*16 + j`?

Tags: arrays, indexing

I'm indexing an array and the function that finds 2-d element is i*16 + j:

```
function ArrayIndex(i,j) {
    return i*16 + j;
}
```

I use this function like such follows:

```
matrix[ArrayIndex(5,6)] // example
```

How do I find inverse function of this `IndexToIj`:

```
function IndexToIj(index) {
   return index/16 - j  //  (??????????)
}
```

This is not correct but I tried my best. What would be inverse of `i*16 + j`? This function returns the `i` and `j` for `index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple equation:
index = i * 16 + j

Inverses:

```
i = (index - j) / 16

j = index - i * 16
```